# Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404

Я загрузил свой orchard веб сайт на хостинг. В `wwwroot` я создал папку `slider` и туда закинул jpg файлы. Когда я пытаюсь открыть jpg файл через url `mysite.ru/slider/1.jpg` я получаю ошибку

> "Server Error in '/' Application. The
>   resource cannot be found"

Я попытался открыть любой другой файл jpg, который уже был загружен вместе с orchard. В папке `Themes/TheThemeMachine` нашел файл `Theme.png`. по url `mysite.ru/Themes/TheThemeMachine/Theme.png` файл открылся в браузере. Я попробовал загрузить `1.jpg` в ту же папку и результат один и тот же

> Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.

Файл точно там, я его вижу по FTP. Я попробовал сделать тоже самое на `localhost` и мне выдается та же ошибка. 
Вот мой `web.config`:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <remove name="host" />
      <remove name="pages" />
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="Orchard.Mvc.ViewEngines.Razor.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
        <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
        <add namespace="Orchard.Mvc.Html"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Убедитесь что у аккоунта ASP.NET (например Network Services на серверах Windows Server 2008) права доступа к новым файлам такие же как и у старых (как минимум Read).